# Como somar elementos de um array que é um retorno de outro function em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo fazer essa soma, retorna NaN, alguma sugestão? 
ps: Sou iniciante em JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está no index dentro do laço `for` da array que está ultrapassando o número de elementos:

```
            aqui está o erro
                  ↓
for(var i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++){
    soma += numbers[i];
}
```

O correto seria:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    soma += numbers[i];
}
```

Como você é iniciante, vou listar os index da array:

```
numbers[0] = 1;
numbers[1] = 2;
numbers[2] = 3;
numbers[3] = 4;
numbers[4] = 5;
numbers[5] = 6;
numbers[6] = 7;
numbers[7] = 8;
numbers[8] = 9;
numbers[9] = 10;
```

O index das arrays sempre começa com `0`, logo, para percorrer toda a array, é preciso especificar no laço `for` que a variável (`i=0`) seja menor que o tamanho `length` da array.

Neste caso, a array possui 10 elementos, mas o laço `for` deve terminar em `9` porque começa com `0`, ou seja, de 0 a 9 são 10 loops.

Comment: Continua retornando NaN :(

Comment: @HerbertCordeiro Vc quer somar todos os valores da array?

Comment: Sim, todos os valores do array que retorna a função range.

Comment: @HerbertCordeiro Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: haha nem percebi isso cara, comecei JS esses dias, só tive experiência com python e java, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

```js
//somar todos arrays

let teste = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let soma = 0

for (let i=0; i<teste.length;i++){
    soma += teste[i]
}

console.log(soma)
```

Comment: tenta esse fi, pra ver se da certo